# Connecting to Firebird using ODBC

Tags: odbc, firebird, interbase, interbase-2009

I have downloaded [`Firebird_ODBC_2.0.4.155_Win32`](http://firebirdsql.org/en/odbc-driver/). I have also started `ODBC` Data Sources from the Control Panel. Now I cant find Firebird/InterBase  driver in the Drivers Tab. I am sure that I installed Firebird. Why?

Comment: Have you started the 32-bit or the 64-bit ODBC administrator?

Comment: Is there a reason you have tagged interbase and interbase-2009 if your question is about Firebird and its ODBC driver?

Answer (score 1):

As already hinted on by Álvaro González in the comments, a 64 bit Windows has two ODBC Data Sources: a 64 bit (for 64 bit applications) and a 32 bit (for 32 bit applications).

As you downloaded and installed the 32 bit Firebird ODBC driver, you will only be able to see it in the 32 bit ODBC Data Sources:

[image: ODBC Data Sources (32 bit) with Firebird driver]

If you need the driver in a 64 bit application, you will also need to download and install the `Firebird_ODBC_2.0.4.155_x64.exe` installer from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/odbc-driver/.